# How to sort list based upon data-id?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a list as like below,

```
<ul> 
    <li data-id="5">Test</li>
    <li data-id="5">abc</li>
    <li data-id="2">data</li>
    <li data-id="4">abc</li>
    <li data-id="3">aazt</li>
</ul>
```

I'm sorting the just based upon the names like,

```
$('li').tsort();
```

How can i make the sorting to consider `data-id` along with the `names` for all the list items ?

In my case the desired output should be like,

```
data
aazt
abc
abc
Test
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7anC/)

Comment: What does the documentation of the plugin you are using tell you?

Comment: Sorry for the mesk, just updated the question as per my requirement. I need both data-id as primary then name as secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass an additional option as `{attr:'data-id'}`

```
$('li').tsort({attr:'data-id'});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/s7anC/1/

**Edit**

The plugin don't support multiple attribute sorting, although you could use them as combined,

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="5" data-combine="5Test">Test</li>
    <li data-id="5" data-combine="5abc">abc</li>
    <li data-id="2" data-combine="2data">data</li>
    <li data-id="4" data-combine="4abc">abc</li>
    <li data-id="3" data-combine="3aazt">aazt</li>
</ul>
```

Note: I suppose you writing the list by iterating so you could make the combine data attribute,

```
$('li').tsort({attr:'data-combine'});
```

check over here http://jsfiddle.net/s7anC/2/

Answer (score 0):

Without any external plugin , this do what you want :

```
$('ul').append($('ul li').sort(function(a,b){
   return parseInt(a.getAttribute('data-id'),10)-parseInt(b.getAttribute('data-id'),10)
}));
```

### DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zucBj/)